# No AirDrop option on iPhone 4s

Tags: iphone, ios, airdrop

I have an iPhone 4s running iOS 8.3. I am trying to send a file from a Mac to the iPhone through AirDrop. Mac notifies that

> if I want to share a file with someone using iOS, he/she must open Control Center and enable AirDrop.

However, I tried to follow these steps, but there is no AirDrop option on my iPhone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iPhone 4s doesn't support AirDrop. You need an iPhone 5 or newer.

Comment: ah - that'll do it every time - well spotted @grgarside :)

Answer (score -1):

iPhone 4s
iOS 8.3

Jailbreak
Install Cydia
Install Repo
Search & Instal Airdrop
Thank me later!